# Model does not appear in admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have seen this question many times, but none of them answer my question.
I have added an app and its models, but don't see them in the admin portal.
I can access the model from shell.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'myApp',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'RCOSPortal.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^RCOSPortal/', include('RCOSPortal.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myApp.models import Owner

admin.site.register(Owner)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you have run the 'syncdb' command.
- Create a
  OwnerAdmin and try to register it.
- If not working upload your test
  project (including all files) in github, so that we could help you.

Comment: I think `admin.site.register(Owner)` is enough to include the model in admin site. Creating an admin class in not mandatory.

Comment: @arulmr Yes. it is optional. Trying brute force :P

Comment: What was your solution, please elaborate. I am having the same issue.